# What is the difference between various kinds of webservers

Tags: django, apache, web-applications, webserver, gunicorn

When PaaS comes into picture, I hear a lot of words *`NGINX, uWSGI, Gunicorn, lighthttpd, Apache`* .. etc.

This should be absolutely novice question. but what I primarily know is

> A webserver listens requests performs operations and returns
>   response

Now what I want to know is, what's the difference between

`NGINX, lighthttpd, Apache, uWSGI` and `Gunicorn..etc` both of these groups are web servers but what is the difference and where they are used?

I use a platform like openshift where they actually use Apache and we got to internally port it by using wsgi server..

Can I use NGINX or lighthttd instead of uWSGI or Gunicorn?

Comment: I'm guessing you aren't the late Dennis Ritchie? :-)

Comment: Just for info, uWSGI is a server, but not an http server. It's an interface between the http server and the web framework/application, so it doesn't make part of this category.

Comment: I have no experience with it, but it seems to be also a good stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very broad question.

Web servers all serve web pages using the HTTP protocol. Check this comparison chart on Wikipedia for a lot of information about lots of web servers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software